# WKWebView load request while previous is not finished already

Tags: wkwebview

I have issue with WKWebView when loading request while loading another. When second request starts loading WKWebView throws error

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={_WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x170230260>
```

I have tried calling stopLoading (if web view is already loading request) before loading new request, but it's not helpful.

Please help me to find the solution for canceling load request and start another.

My temporary solution is to wait for first request to finish then start another.

Comment: got anything solved? :)